# `LoadLibraryExW` triggers exception `0xC0000023` from `NtMapViewOfSection`

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, activex, seh

It's going to be really hard to reduce the scope of this question, but here we go.

#### Context

I'm in the context of a 32-bit ActiveX control which is loaded into a host (`TstCon.exe`). After unloading and reloading the control, I receive a streak of errors from `NtMapViewOfSection`, the first of which occurs when `odbc32.dll` uses `LoadLibraryExW` to load `C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll`. At that point, an SEH exception is emitted from somewhere inside `NtMapViewOfSection` with code `0xC0000023` (AKA `STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL` according to the debugger).

#### Aftermath

Here's what the callstack looks like when the debugger intercepts the exception:

```
ntdll.dll!_NtMapViewOfSection@40()
KernelBase.dll!BasepLoadLibraryAsDataFileInternal()
KernelBase.dll!BasepLoadLibraryAsDataFile()
KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW()
odbc32.dll!_InitializeDll@0()
odbc32.dll!_SQLAllocEnv@4()
<OurDll>.dll!<OurFunction>()
...
```

At that point, I've used *perfectly sane* techniques to retrieve the arguments to the call to `NtMapViewOfSection` by following [this documentation](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FSection%2FNtMapViewOfSection.html):

```
*(void**)(ESP + 4 + 0)           /*SectionHandle*/      0x000003b0              void *
*(void**)(ESP + 4 + 4)           /*ProcessHandle*/      0xffffffff              void *
*(void**)(ESP + 4 + 8)           /*BaseAddress*/        0x00daae30              void *
*(unsigned long*)(ESP + 4 + 12)  /*ZeroBits*/           0x00000000              unsigned long
*(unsigned long*)(ESP + 4 + 16)  /*CommitSize*/         0x00000000              unsigned long
*(long long**)(ESP + 4 + 20)     /*SectionOffset*/      0x00000000 {???}        __int64 *
*(unsigned long**)(ESP + 4 + 24) /*ViewSize*/           0x00daae28 {0x00000000} unsigned long *
*(int*)(ESP + 4 + 28)            /*InheritDisposition*/ 0x00000001              int
*(unsigned long*)(ESP + 4 + 32)  /*AllocationType*/     0x00800000              unsigned long
*(unsigned long*)(ESP + 4 + 36)  /*Protect*/            0x00000002              unsigned long
```

#### Assembly walkthrough

I have originally caught the exception by enabling break-on-throw in VS's debugger, then I've been able to pinpoint the first failing call and place a breakpoint just ahead. Here is what I can see from debugging inside the disassembly (`>` marks the current instruction):

```
  _NtMapViewOfSection@40:
  76F2EF60  mov         eax,28h  
  76F2EF65  mov         edx,offset _Wow64SystemServiceCall@0 (76F43430h)  
> 76F2EF6A  call        edx  
  76F2EF6C  ret         28h  
  76F2EF6F  nop
```

... *step into*:

```
  _Wow64SystemServiceCall@0:
> 76F43430  jmp         dword ptr [_Wow64Transition (76FD2218h)]
```

... *step into*:

```
> 74A37000  jmp         0033:74A37009  
  74A37007  add         byte ptr [eax],al  
  74A37009  inc         ecx  
  74A3700A  jmp         dword ptr [edi+0F8h]
```

... *step into*:

```
  _NtQueryObject@20:
  76F2EDC0  mov         eax,10h  
  76F2EDC5  mov         edx,offset _Wow64SystemServiceCall@0 (76F43430h)  
  76F2EDCA  call        edx  
> 76F2EDCC  ret         14h  
  76F2EDCF  nop
```

And the next *step into* triggers the exception.

---

Disturbances to the program's environment, such as:

- Updating compilers and runtimes (between MSVC90 and MSVC141), which revealed the bug in the first place;
- Switching between Release and Debug configurations;
- Forcing a base address for the OCX through the `/base` linker flag;
- Running with a debugger attached;
- Monitoring system calls with `drstrace.exe`;

... change which calls to `NtMapViewOfSection` will succeed or fail, seemingly at random: not all of them fail, but a considerable number do. In fact, the first occurence of the error is probably not indicative of where the problem actually originates from, as I've rarely been able to make it crash earlier (upon unloading the control), and even obtained a crash where *none* of our code was on the callstack (through quitting `TstCon.exe` directly).

I can't find any documentation (official or otherwise) mentioning `STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL` or the `0xC0000023` code in this context. I've been unable to find a pattern in the failing calls, and saw no relevant access errors from a Dr. Memory run.

So... What could possibly be happening inside this process for such symptoms to appear?

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean Windows Defender screwing up somehow when hooking the call? It's worth a shot. Edit: no dice, the exception still fires.

Comment: When I had problems like this in the past it was always, ALWAYS, caused by some kind of wild write.

Comment: I am guessing that hosting the control in OleView is fine? If you create an empty console app that simply initializes Ole, loads and unloads nothing will ever go wrong? There are inprocess things you can use to catch heap corruptions in both the CRT and HeapAlloc spaces and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags can be used to turn on debug flags to pad all allocations and throw exceptions if over or underwrites happen.

Comment: `NtMapViewOfSection` **return** `STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL` (this api must never return this status) or **raise** exception instead return (even less likely - not believe ). however in this case debugger must stop inside `KiRaiseUserExceptionDispatcher`  (can set bp here - extremely rarely called). again callstack - can not be this if you direct not stop inside `NtMapViewOfSection`. on which instruction ? what show debugger at all ? anyway sure your description of problem is wrong

Comment: @RbMm `NtMapViewOfSection` throws an exception with that status code. I've caught it by enabling break-on-throw in the debugger. Then I was able to place a breakpoint just before the first failing call and follow through the assembly, but it seems like I hit a kernel boundary and can't step further inside. I'm goind to update my answer with what I see.

Comment: @Quentin - kernel code can "throw" exception in user mode only via call to `KeRaiseUserException(STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL)` as result code return from kernel to `ntdll.KiRaiseUserExceptionDispatcher` (set breakpoint to it !). inside this api exist call to `RtlRaiseException` which actual trow exception in user mode. however based on my knowledge and experience i sure that you wrong - `NtMapViewOfSection` not throw any exception. this do another code. and your callstack also not from exception. need more correct info or better look in debugger

Comment: @RbMm I just tried setting a breakpoint inside `KiRaiseUserExceptionDispatcher` (which VS resolved to `_KiRaiseUserExceptionDispatcher@0()`). The breakpoint is active, but is never hit. Please see the updated question for what I've been able to see through debugging.

Comment: @Quentin - i not take to account that you run wow64 (32 bit code in 64 bit system). in this case exist 2 ntdll (32 and 64 bit) in process - you call `NtMapViewOfSection` from 32 bit ntdll. the `0033:74A37009` is enter to 64 bit user code, which really can raise some exception before call `NtMapViewOfSection` from 64 bit ntdll. however you can enter to 64 bit code and continue debug with some debuggers. say with windbg. use it and enter to `0033:74A37009` for look exactly where problem (code here not too big). the msvc debugger not good here

Comment: this is how look like 64 bit part of map view of section in wow - https://prnt.sc/lw4i3x. you need mandatory install pad symbols and use windbg for view where exactly this call fail. enter to 64 code

Comment: @RbMm mmh, that explains why the debugger seems to jump around randomly. Unfortunately starting the program under WinDbg has triggered *another* volatile bug (**groan**) which I'll have to fix first. But this sounds promising, I'll get back to it tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking at the ActiveX control's execution for a long time, using the debugger to skip over specific sections of code, I narrowed the possible location of the bug down to a single function. It turns out that the origin of the problem was pretty impossible to guess.

Someone, someday, wanted to be able to give names to threads. To this end, they used the documented [`0x406D1388`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-a-thread-name-in-native-code?view=vs-2017#set-a-thread-name-by-throwing-an-exception) technique (in fact, the code is pretty much copy-pasted from the linked documentation). This, in itself, is fine. But then they wanted (or so I gather) to retrieve the name programmatically, which is not supported by the custom exception method. This was all before `SetThreadDescription`/`GetThreadDescription` existed, so they looked for another way. And *man* were they inventive.

Alongside the call to the function that threw the custom exception were the following lines:

```
// Grab the TIB.
P_T_TIB pTib = GetTIB();

if (pTib == NULL)
    return false;

// If someone has already written to the arbitrary field, I don't
// want to be overwriting it.
if (pTib->pvArbitrary == NULL)
{
    // Nothing's there. Set the name.
    pTib->pvArbitrary = (void *)pszName;
}
```

What's there, of course, is definitely not "nothing". `GetTIB` is defined as follows:

```
// A static function to get the TIB.
static P_T_TIB GetTIB()
{
    P_T_TIB pTib = NULL;

    _asm
    {
        MOV  EAX, FS:[18h]
        MOV  pTib, EAX
    }

    return pTib;
}
```

This piece of highly suspicious assembly, as I learned, retrieves a pointer to the [Thread Information Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) of the current thread. `T_TIB`'s definition follows what's described on that page and allows the thread-naming function to store a pointer to the name into the Arbitrary Data Slot. This same technique was used in the name-getting function to retrieve the pointer and return the name.

Of course, the hitch is that "arbitrary" does not mean "user data", and `NtMapViewOfSection` and friends rely on the field to store information, as evidenced by a data breakpoint placed on the field that was hit by `LdrpMapViewOfSection`, among others. Somewhere along their path, encountering the field with an abnormally non-zero value (that is, our name pointer) caused them to perform some *very wrong* operation which ended up triggering that weird exception.

For the curious, I completely removed all of that, as it wasn't used anywhere else, and simply used a `thread_local` variable to store the name. Case closed!